# Convert old NuSoap code into PHP core soap functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap, nusoap

I've been testing nuSoap with codeIgniter (PHP Framework) but seems nuSoap isn't prepared to work with latest php 5.3, even if I download a patched nusoap version for php 5.3

I have the following code:

`require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/NuSOAP/lib/nusoap'.EXT); //includes nusoap`
`$n_params = array('CityName' => 'San Juan', 'CountryName' => 'Argentina');`
`$client = new nusoap_client('http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL');`
`$client->setHTTPProxy("10.2.0.1",6588,"","");`
`$result = $client->call('GetWeather', $n_params);`

Can you help me to convert these functions into PHP soap functions? Including proxy function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/NuSOAP/lib/nusoap'.EXT); //includes nusoap
$n_params = array('CityName' => 'San Juan', 'CountryName' => 'Argentina');
$client = new nusoap_client('http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL');
$client->setHTTPProxy("10.2.0.1",6588,"","");
$result = $client->call('GetWeather', $n_params);
```

becomes

```
$url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL';
$params = array(
    'proxy_host' => '10.2.0.1',
    'proxy_port' => '6588'
    );
$client = new SoapClient($url, $params);
$client->__soapCall('GetWeather', $n_params);
```

Comment: @Enrique Where do you set $n_params ?

Comment: Hi Ivo. I've fixed everything, but now I'm having trouble with SSL, which is another world. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The following code was the correct way of calling the above webservice. I've just only modified the $ser_params array. Now it has a sub array

`$url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL';`
`$conn_params = array(`
`'proxy_host' => '10.2.0.1',`
`'proxy_port' => '6588'`
`);`

`$ser_params = array (`
`'GetWeather' => array (`
`"CityName" => "San Juan",`
`"CountryName" => "Argentina"`
`)`
`);`

`$client = new SoapClient($url, $conn_params);`
`$result = $client->__soapCall('GetWeather', $ser_params);`
`print_r ($result);`